# Check parent from ditamap

Tags: xsl-fo, dita

I have the following problem. I need somehow to know, that I am processing topicref, that is inside of preface.

So I have following ditamap (its of course part of it).

```
<frontmatter>
    <preface href="preface.dita">
            <topicref href="somethingp1.dita"></topicref>
            <topicref href="somethingp2.dita"></topicref>
            <topicref href="somethingp3.dita"></topicref>
    </preface>
</frontmatter>
<chapter href="something.dita">
    <topicref href="something2.dita"/>
    <topicref href="something3.dita"/>
</chapter>
```

Now the question is, can I somehow check if I am processing topicref from preface and not from chapter.

To be more specific, I have to specify different attributes for p tag that is used in preface (because maybe there is better way to do it).

Is it possible?

Comment: Which output format are you working on? PDF? Are you using DITA Open Toolkit or some other tool?

Comment: PDF and I am using DITA OT - yes. Actually I already solved it, by using $map variable. Sorry for REALLY late answer and thank you for participation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps you:

```
<xsl:template match="//topicref">
    <xsl:if test="name(parent::*) = 'preface'">
        ... do something
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```